# How can I create an alternating list pattern with just CSS

Tags: css

[image]

I have a list of items with an alternating colour pattern on a screen 991px and above. I am using CSS to target each child element that I want to change the colour off.

However, my CSS does not seem very elegant as the number of items is unknown and could be in the hundreds. With my CSS approach I would have to write out all the possibilities to ensure the styling is retained.

Is there a way with CSS that my approach can be improved on?

```
@media screen and (min-width:991px) {

    .item {
        background:darkgrey;
    }

    .item:nth-child(2),
    .item:nth-child(3),
    .item:nth-child(6),
    .item:nth-child(7),
    .item:nth-child(10),
    .item:nth-child(11),
    .item:nth-child(14),
    .item:nth-child(15),
    .item:nth-child(18),
    .item:nth-child(19),
    .item:nth-child(22),
    .item:nth-child(23),
    .item:nth-child(26),
    .item:nth-child(27) ,
    .item:nth-child(30)  {
        background:green;
    }
}
```

Comment: To make it a bit more clear: This looks like altering colors but in reality it is blue, green, green, blue blue, green, green etc...
So this it is not really a duplicate question of the ones above.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [functional notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#functional_notation)

```
.item:nth-child(4n+2),
.item:nth-child(4n+3) { background: green }
```

Comment: `even` or `2n` isn't the same as `2, 3, 6, 7`, etc. as mentioned in the OP code.

Comment: @pavel indeed, fixed. I had misread the question.

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted. See https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: @Roel: it was my downvote, read my comment above (and original answer before it was edited).